# При создании проекта на Django выбило ошибку NoReverseMatch от url, который даже не вызываю

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

[image: Сама ошибка]

Вот код html:

```
{% for article in object_list %}
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <span class="font-weight-bold">
                    <a href="{% url 'article_detail' article.pk %}">
                        {{ article.title }}
                    </a>
                </span> &middot;
                <span class="text-muted">by {{ article.author }} | {{ article.date }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-center text-muted">
                <a href="{% url 'article_edit' article.pk %}">Edit</a> |
                <a href="{% url 'article_delete' article.pk %}">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    {% endfor %}
```

Вот url:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ArticleListView,
    ArticleUpdateView,
    ArticleDetailView,
    ArticleDeleteView,
    ArticleCreateView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', ArticleUpdateView.as_view(), name='article_edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', ArticleDeleteView.as_view(), name='article_delete'),
    path('new/', ArticleCreateView.as_view(), name='article_new'),
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='article_list'),
]
```

Вот view:

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_detail.html'
```

Вот модель:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article_detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Начнём издалека: если весь этот код html стереть, ошибка пропадает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вы показали шаблон, относящийся к представлению списка статей, хотя ошибка у вас возникает когда вы открываете отдельную статью, возможно такое?

В любом случае, ищите в ваших шаблонах (по идее, это должен быть шаблон `article_detail.html`) тег без аргументов:

```
{% url 'article_delete' %}
```

И меняйте на:

```
{% url 'article_delete' article.pk %}
```

Думаю, именно в этом проблема. Шаблон из вашего вопроса, похоже, правильный и ошибок вызывать не должен.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Ошибка из-за невнимательности.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переписать view как-то так:

```
class ArticleDetailView(request, DetailView):
   object_list = Article.objects.get(pk=DetailView)
   return render(request, ''article_detail.html'', {'object_list': object_list})
```

У Вас во view не указано что возвращать, и не указано какие данные отправлять в html. Пример: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/

Comment: Так ведь наследование от DetailView уже предполагает, что будет возвращаться объект. В другом проекте это работало, а здесь нет. Возможно опечатка в книге.

Comment: А, точно, извините, не разобралась. Ваш view в этом случае правильный...